# Does more trading posts mean more traders?

Tags: banished

If I build more trading posts, will more trade boats show up? Seeing as trade boats are the only non-exhaustible source of stone and iron, I'd like to know how to make the most of them.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yes, multiple trading posts means more trade boats. PeebleTheory confirmed this in [this video](http://www.twitch.tv/peebletheory/c/3712360). At ~4:30 a second trade boat comes by while he is already trading with one trade boat and it goes to his second trading post.